# Why doesn't the "-" change back to letters?

Tags: java

So I'm playing Wheel of fortune/hangman and I've converted the letters of the solution to "-" to hide the solution. Now I'm trying to convert them back to letters after the user has guessed them correctly. However when a correct letter is entered, only "-" are printed. Here's my code:
Puzzle.java:

```
public class Puzzle
{
    /** The solution is the complete word or phrase that is to be guessed */
    private String solution="BIG JAVA";


    /**
     * The puzzle is the word or phrase that is to be guessed with hyphens for
     * all unguessed letters. Initially the puzzle should include all hyphens
     * for all letters in the solution. As the user guesses a letter the hyphens
     * for that letter are replaced with the letter.
     */
    private StringBuilder puzzle;


    /**
     * Constructs a new Puzzle object with the given puzzle solution. Puzzles
     * can contain any character and should be case insensitive. This
     * constructor should set the current state of the puzzle so the all letters
     * in the puzzle are set to a hyphen. All non letter values should be left
     * unchanged in the puzzle.  The puzzle should be set to the solution passed
     * in.
     * 
     * @param solution the solution to the puzzle
     */
    public Puzzle(String Solution)
    {
        puzzle=new StringBuilder(this.solution);
        int length= this.solution.length();
        for(int count=0; count<length; count++)
        {
            if (Character.isLetter(puzzle.charAt(count)))
            {
                puzzle.setCharAt(count, '-');
            }
        }



    }


    /** 
     * The guessLetter method is used to determine how many times the letter
     * that is passed in occurs in the puzzle. If the letter has already been
     * guessed previously, this method should return zero. This method should be
     * case insensitive. In other words 'H' is the same as 'h'.  After a call to
     * to this method the puzzle should be updated to remove the hyphen from
     * the location in the puzzle for each occurrence of the letter.
     * 
     * @param letter
     *            the letter that the user is guessing
     * @return the number of times the letter occurs in the solution only if the
     *         letter has not already been guessed. If the letter has been
     *         previously guessed this method should return 0.
     */
    public int guessLetter(char letter)
    {
        int count = 0;
        int k=this.solution.length();
        solution.equalsIgnoreCase(solution);
        for(int seq=0; seq<k; seq++)
        {
            if(solution.charAt(seq)==letter)
            {
                count++;                
                puzzle.setCharAt(seq, letter);

            }
        }

        return count;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * The getPuzzle method should return the current state of the puzzle. The
     * puzzle should include a hyphen for any letters that have not been guessed.
     * 
     * @return the current state of the puzzle
     */
    public String getPuzzle()
    {
        String str=new String(puzzle);


        return str;
    }

    /**
     * The solvePuzzle method is used to verify that a solution passed in
     * matches the solution to this puzzle. The check for matching solutions
     * should be case insensitive.
     * 
     * @param solution
     * @return true if the solution passed in matches the solution for the
     *         puzzle
     */
    public boolean solvePuzzle(String solution)
    {
        if(this.solution==solution)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;

        }

    }

}
```

PuzzleTester.java:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class PuzzleTester
{

    /**
     * (Insert a brief description that describes the purpose of this method) 
     *
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String str="";

        Scanner input= new Scanner(System.in);


        System.out.println("Enter your choice: ");
        System.out.println("(1) to guess a letter");
        System.out.println("(2) to solve the puzzle");
        System.out.println("(3) to quit");
        int choice=input.nextInt();

        while(choice!=3)
        {           
            if(choice==1)
            {
                System.out.println("Please enter your letter");
                str=input.next();

                char letter=str.charAt(0);
                Puzzle game=new Puzzle(str);
                game.guessLetter(letter);

                System.out.print(game.getPuzzle());
            }

            if(choice==2)
            {
                System.out.println("Please solve the puzzle");
                input.nextLine();
                String solution=input.next();
                Puzzle game=new Puzzle(solution);
                game.solvePuzzle(solution);
            }


        }

        if(choice==3)
            {
                System.out.println("Good Bye");
            }


    }

}
```

I really thought that adding `puzzle.setCharAt(seq, letter);` in the nested if statement in the for loop under the guessLetter method would change the "-" back to the letter. Is my code just wrong, or is there a better way?

Comment: I think `solution.equalsIgnoreCase(solution)` does not do quite what you think it does. All it is doing is comparing `solution` to itself, in a case-insensitive way, which will obviously always return true! The method does not change the `solution` String, as Strings are immutable in Java. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equalsIgnoreCase(java.lang.String)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot compare strings like that:

```
if (this.solution==solution)
```

Solution is never used in constructor:

```
    public Puzzle(String Solution)
```

Your game object is reset on every step. You must create it once.

Comment: Ok so I changed `if(this.solution.equalsIgnoreCase(solution))` to fix that issue. But I don't understand is how my puzzel object is reset every time. Do I just need to take out the `String Solution` in the condition?

Comment: If I do take out the condition of Puzzle, then the `Puzzle game=new Puzzle(str);` becomes undefined in the puzzletester class.

Comment: I mean: you create a new Puzzle every time the user makes a choice. You should define the "game" variable outside the while loop

Comment: Ok my problem is that the letters are case sensitive. I need to change that to ignorecase. I thought I did that but I guess I didn't do it in the right place.